# On the explanation of facts

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reference-request, causation, scientific-method

As a chemist, I have some philosophical doubts about explanation of facts.

**Short intro**

In Bertrand Russell's book 'History of Western Philosophy' he says that leading-to scientific knowledge is the 'why', not in a sense of *purpose* but in a sense of *causation*. So, to explain facts, in science, we use the cause. In this sense, it should be enough to say "A produces B" as explanation of facts. Theories are powerful tools for that purpose. A theory, as quantum theory, is accepted only if it has been validated with experience. After that, its results can be used as explanations.

Taken into account the last paragraph, I wonder what are the ways in which we explain by using the cause. In the macroscopic world, as said, it is enough to say 'A produce B'. But then there are theories. The explanation is called [reductionist](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/47304/reductionism-as-explanation-of-facts) if tends to explain the whole as the interaction of the parts. In this way, biology tends to chemistry and it tends to particle physics. There is also a kind of explanation in the *same layer*. For example, thermodynamics explain the macroscopic world in term of constants, and so on.

**An example in chemistry**

If we ask why liquid water evaporates from a glass in the sun, the answer can be made in terms of thermodynamics or statistical thermodynamics; same layer or a lower one, respectively.

**Question**

I suppose there are more ways of explanation of facts, and want to read a complete answer or an essay about this subject.

Any interesting reference on this problem?

Comment: THe idea of explanation has changed (and maybe iy will change in the future). For ancient and medieval philosophers, thing were and act as they were by way of having *virtues* (inner properties) to do that way: bodies fall because they are heavy.

Comment: If it is so, it hasn't changed. That's a theory..@MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: +1 See Mumford and Anjum's "Causation" for a survey starting with Hume and ending with dispositionalism. https://www.amazon.com/Causation-Very-Short-Introduction-Introductions/dp/019968443X Aristotle's four causes are still relevant. See Jack Sander's lectures on philosophy of science for an overview of the topic.  If I remember correctly he puts a positive spin on Aristotle's four causes.

Comment: @FrankHubeny Great! Thanks. Reading your comment I remembered Schopenahuer's 'on the four root of..'. Do you think is a good source?

Comment: I haven't read Schopenhauer, so I wouldn't know how he fits into this.

Comment: If you're interested in non-reductive explanations, I recommend [Sandra Mitchell's *Unsimple Truths*](https://books.google.com/books?id=obbUPu0HbHEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=sandra+mitchell&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-s7nV-9fZAhWKhlQKHaD7CioQ6AEIKDAA).

Comment: Causation can be irreducible to a simpler level. Reductionism is a tool not a stance. It's converse is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergentism which has only really been accessible to analysis in recent timed, with computer simulations and processing power.